# Find orthogonal matrix P such that $PAP^{-1}=B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an Orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}=B,$ where

$A = \;\;\;
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ and 
$B = \;\;\;
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

How to find such an orthogonal matrix $P$ ?  I solved the problems in which $B$ is a diagonal matrix. Now in this $B$ is a jordan block matrix of order $3.$ I read something about jordan canonical form but did't get the method to find such type of orthogonal matrix. Please explane how to solve this type of problems. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that

- $A$ can be transformed to $B$ by first switching the first two rows, then the first two columns,
- permutation matrices are orthogonal,
- Row (column) operations correspond to a multiplication of a matrix from the left (right).

Comment: row and column both?

Comment: then how to find required matrix?

Comment: There's a good discussion here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationMatrix.html @neela

Comment: is there no general theory of jordan canonical form ?

Comment: Yes, there are of course. But in this case I don't think that is easier. @neela (Edit: It seems that using the general procedure, you could at best find an invertible $P$, this $P$ might not be orthogonal)

Comment: yes i got the point....thanking you....

Comment: yes i think this question is basically meant for this methods only...